# Entity field not being saved

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, MVC 5.1, EF 6.0, targeting .NET 4.5. Code-first, with a default connection string.

I've got a really simple entity, named `SchoolModel`, listed below.

```
public class SchoolModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    [Display(Name="School Name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

I used the scaffolding feature to create the standard MVC5 view/controller combo, named School and SchoolController respectively. I'm trying to add a few school records to the database.

The Create view:

```
@model OddsOnEnglish.GamingIELTS.Web.Models.SchoolModel

[snip]

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SchoolModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new {@class="col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

SchoolController.Create:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] SchoolModel schoolModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Schools.Add(schoolModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(schoolModel);
}
```

`db` above is an instance of `SchoolContext`:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Models.SchoolModel> Schools { get; set; }
}
```

All pretty straightforward, and based off of various tutorials. My issue is that when I submit the create school form, the index page is shown again with a new row for the new school, but no name is shown. Looking into the database, rows do get added to the corresponding table, but with only a value in the Id column - nothing for Name. If I manually enter a name in the database, that will then show up in the web interface. Clearly the record is being created, but the Name field is not being populated.

Comment: don't use private set..and try...

Comment: @Exception Thanks for catching that. Such a simple thing! Want to post an answer for it?

Comment: posted the answer...@Grant Palin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Correct your model as :

```
public class SchoolModel
{
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Display(Name="School Name")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**this problem you are facing because of private set block just correct it.**

Comment: Such an obvious issue I was passing over. Apparently needed other eyes to catch it. The model is fixed and a lesson learned.

Comment: Great...always learn a lesson from your mistakes...thankzz...@GrantPalin